# Converting rows to columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am struggling to ***dynamically*** convert the row <-> column in mysql. I have looked a few questions in SO and the nearest I could find is this: [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

This is the original table:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+
|  name     |  type      |   marks  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
|  thaqif   |  Quiz 1    |   5.oo   |
+-----------+------------+----------+
|  ajis     |  Quiz 1    |   5.00   |
+-----------+------------+----------+
|  thaqif   |  Test      |   25.00  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
|  ajis     |  test      |   25.00  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
```

My desired output would be like this:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+
|  name     |  Quiz 1    |   Test   |
+-----------+------------+----------+
|  thaqif   |  5.00      |   25.oo  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
|  ajis     |  5.00      |   25.00  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
```

This is the code that I have modified:

```
SET @SQL = NULL;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT('count(case when assessment_type = ''',assessment_type,''' then 1 end) AS ',replace(assessment_type, '', '')
        )
    ) INTO @sql
    from studentmarks;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT student_name,', @sql, ' from studentmarks');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

However, the output just displayed one row and the marks was not even correct. I believed there would be something wrong in the ***count()*** function but then, removing the function will show the failed to call ***getClauses()*** function.

UPDATED: The reason why I am looking for dynamic sql is that, the number of assessment type is unknown. Maybe, there would be a presentation or even an assignment inserted by the user. Therefore, the table should be able to display those type of assessment and its marks too

Comment: You don't need dynamic sql for the sample you have given but you do need a group by.

Answer (score 0):

i am giving you simple demonstration you should try like this

```
select s1.name, s1.marks as 'Quiz 1',s2.marks as 'Test' from studentmarks as s1 join studentmarks as s2 on s1.name = s2.name and s2.type = 'test' where s1.type = 'Quiz 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with your statement build 1) count is not appropriate use max 2) of marks 3) you are not catering for the situation where a student does not have an assessment type - the case should have an else 0 4) the replace does not remove spaces in the assessment type 5) the group_concat should include a distinct clause to avoid duplicates 6) there is no group by in the final select